# Sign Recognition with using Java Mars

Tags: java, eclipse, comparison, accelerometer

I have a graduation project that is sign recognition. I want to compare similarities between accelerometer values in order to detect accelerometer values in sensors. One accelerometer value is in the database and the other accelerometer value is taking from smart glove with using Java code dynamically. My smart glove is Acceleglove. I am thinking that I have to use dynamic time warping algorithm. What is your suggestions? Thank you.

```
int DTWDistance(s: array [1..n], t: array [1..m])
```

Comment: can you give an example?

Comment: What kind of example do you want? Sorry, I did not understand your question.

Comment: " I want to compare similarities between accelerometer values in order to detect accelerometer values in sensors." Give us an example of two accelerometer values, the similarity that you want to *compute* (not "compare", I guess), and how that helps you detect accelerometer values in sensors.